# Can normal functions emulate OOP?

Tags: php, functional-programming

Can OOP programming be emulated with just normal functions? Like with using static variables and anonymous functions: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: static variables and anonymous functions can be used when coding in a procedural style just as readily as when programming in an object-oriented style

Comment: That was a lot of fun; thanks for asking!

Comment: Just noticed you have `functional-programming` tag. It is inconsistent with the question title and body. Functional programming requires that functions don't have access to the "state" of a program (such as the an object instance, or some other means of storing dynamic values), and the function can take dynamic information only through params and the function can only return and never write to any state variables. Functional-programming can never be OOP, and that tag should be replaced with the `procedural-programming` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOP is about having a constructor function which initiates an object, accessible to other functions "statically" using the `this` keyword.

So yes, you can do OOP without using language constructs such as "class", "this", or __construct.

**Normal OOP**:

```
class Something{
    public $member_var;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->member_var="x";
    }

    public function fill($strValue){
        $this->member_var=$strValue;
    }
}
$objInstance=new Something();

$objInstance->fill("abc");
```

**OOP using procedural language constructs** (I have avoided the Object class to stay away from any OOP stuff, however it would be better to use it for the $self type, maybe to be able to use the -> accessor, or take advantage of automatic pass by reference):

```
function Something_constructor(&$self){
    $self=array(
        "member_var"=>"x",
    );
}

function fill(&$self, $strValue){
    $self["member_var"]=$strValue;
}

Something_constructor($arrInstance);

fill($arrInstance, "abc");
```

Using PHP >=5.3 new anonymous function feature, you could add member functions as properties inside the $self array/object, more so because you can invoke directly (`$self["fill"]("abcde")`). A nicer accesor is possible if using an object data type for $self.

Depending on how you design your code, this procedural style OOP might be tweaked to work nicely in simple RPC scenarios (however, the constructor will never return a usable $self object/array, so you might as well go full OOP and have the same problem).

If going the (object)array() route, you can store the fill function in the object as a property, yet you will never have a `$this` reference (without passing it as param) or prototypal or any other kind of inheritance. You'd better stick with the class keyword in PHP, there's no reason to go around it.

If you also need inheritance, this is where it gets ugly: you need to create renamed functions for overriding, "type" conversion functions for the `$self` array/object, etc.

It can be done. If you have complex needs (like inheritance) it might get really ugly. If you have really simple needs, not so ugly, maybe even with advantages.

Answer (score 2):

Static variables are used to write procedural code, which at first glance looks like OOP.

OOP is a design pattern , which as nothing to do with which aspect of language you use. You would benefit a lot from reading following article: [OOP vs Procedural Code](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/07/oop-vs-procedural-code.html). It explains for to write an object oriented code (even with only functions).

Also, you should be aware that [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is a completely different development paradigm. There are functional language which are made for this paradigm: JavaScript, Scala, Haskell, Erlang.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest I can imagine quickly would be writing all of your functions to take their first argument as the data structure to operate on. Think of it like this:

OOP is essentially just coupling a known structure of data with appropriate behaviors.

So, if you are willing to trust yourself to only pass data structures that functions know how to work with, you could model it procedurally, with each "class" having two arrays in the global space, one for "instances", and one for "functions" (literally an array of callables, keyed on their name).

I wrote some code which defines "classes" as essentially a collection of methods, and those methods can essentially treat `$self` however they want (so long as they all know what to expect). This is a pretty cool idea (thanks for asking!). Note the use of anonymous functions, which could, in theory, be aggregated into a function-prototypes array and used on many different classes (i.e. just one "description" or "__toString" class, works on all classes).

## edit: working code:

```
<?php

// The "Runtime" //
function makeObject($class, $constructorArgs) {
  global $classes;
  $constructorArgs = (array) $constructorArgs;
  $instance =  $classes[$class]['instances'][] = array();
  $instance['_class'] = $class;
  $instance = callMethod($instance, 'construct', $constructorArgs);
  return $instance;
}
function callMethod($instance, $method, $args = array()) {
  global $classes;
  return call_user_func_array($classes[$instance['_class']]['methods'][$method], array_merge(array($instance), $args));
}

// Class definition for "Person" //
$classes['Person'] = array();
$classes['Person']['methods'] = array();
$classes['Person']['methods']['construct'] = function($self, $name) {
    $self['name'] = $name;
    return $self;
};
$classes['Person']['methods']['sayHello'] = function($self) 
{
    echo "hello, my name is " . $self['name'] . "\n";
};
$classes['Person']['instances'] = array();


// Begin "Application" code.
// equivalent to: 
// $person = new Person("sally");
// $person->sayHello();

$person = makeObject('Person', "sally");
callMethod($person, "sayHello");
```

This can obviously be expanded in any number of fun and interesting ways. For instance, you can rework the structure of the "method" functions to also take a $parent argument, and allow children classes to call their parents, and allow callMethod() to lookup inherited methods when the child does not implement them. This is a lot of fun. Notice that only the last two lines are actually "application code"... the rest is equivalent to declarative "setup" code (analogous to class definitions) and the "runtime" functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you get to the bottom of it, "objects are just records of functions", which is well-known in programming language theory. That is, if you have a language with some record-like feature and proper first-class functions (i.e. "closures"), then a "class" is simply a function that returns such a record. E.g., in some pseudo syntax (since my PHP is rudimentary):

```
func Point(x, y) {
  var my_x = x
  var my_y = y
  var this = {
    getX : func() { return my_x }
    getY : func() { return my_y }
    move : func(dx, dy) { my_x += dx; my_y += dy }
    dist : func() { return sqrt(this.getX()**2 + this.getY()**2) }
  }
  return this
}

var p = Point(0, 3)
p.move(2, -5)
p.getY()  // -2
```

Note how all "methods" are just first-class functions that close over the local variables (which are thus hidden).

If you also want inheritance, then the encoding gets more involved, but is still possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Maybe, for instance, overloading a function in a functional language is somewhat an equivalent of inheritance in OOP, for example. But the point is, you should not even *think* of trying to make code written in a functional language look OOP. Think of them as different tools, to get at the same goals.

OOP *in theory* promotes a cleaner code base and *supposedly* allows for reusing code more easily.
When it came out there was a lot of hype around these concepts, many would even say today it was overhype. Functional languages have regained the respect they deserve in past years,  many people having realised OOP is just a BUZZ word that is by no means a guarantee of code quality.

There are many coding techniques and approaches to functional programming that can make it just as elegant as OOP.  Using the right tool for the job is a good start for any project, using it properly is the major part of where your attention should be. Trying to make a particular project's codebase look like  OOP with a functional language would not bring any benefit and is bound to make someone miserable down the line: if not you, the person that has to maintain it.

One of your main goal is to have a codebase as easy to understand as possible and there are many approaches specific to functional programming that deal with this, just as there are approaches in OOP.  In my (very humble) opinion, functional programming even has an advantage as it is more flexible.

I have seen and managed quite large projects that were a pleasure to work in. And some small OOP projects that were very hard to wrap your head around.  Even using the right tool, in the wrong hands will bring bad results.

My 2 cents, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have different opinions on what OOP really is...
I think that OOP is a methodology to design programs in a very specific way, using the objects as the system metaphors for the program or computations, that helps you imbue your resulting process and software with a lot of extremely nice, useful and powerful qualities.

With that in mind, you can apply the OOP methodology while using any language, it's just a lot easier to do it in some language than in others... It's generally easiest in the "OOP" languages which aren't languages that force you to write OOP code (because that's not possible), but that gives you a set of features, that if you want to follow the OOP methodology, will make your life easier...

Finally, the most difficult "thing" you need to "Emulate OOP" good enough, is the ability to use "behavior" or "code" as data... That can be achieved in a lot of ways, like lambda functions, or first class functions, or function pointers, etc... Most of modern languages support at least one of those.